# Определить количество цифр в числе типа BigInteger в Java

Tags: java, biginteger

Есть число n типа BigInteger. Необходимо определить количество цифр в этом числе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Некрасивый способ

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger("231");
int digits = value.toString(10).length();
```

По-другому некрасивый способ, но уже получше

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger("231");
int digits = 0;
while (!value.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
    value = value.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
    digits++;
}
```

Comment: Зачем в первом случае передавать 10 в скобках?

Comment: @МаркТюков система исчисленния. На самом деле десятичная и так будет использоваться, но explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: В [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString()) не обязательно передавать 10, т.к. это значение по умолчанию. И да, второй способ ни разу не лучше.

Comment: @defaultlocale о чем я и написал

Answer (score -1):

Вот еще вариант для чисел **от 1 до 1 до 99 999 999 999 999** (верхняя граница грубая, т.к. для большинства 15-значных тоже работает, но не всех) с использованием 10го логарифма:

```
private static int logLength(BigInteger i){
    return (int) Math.floor(Math.log10(i.doubleValue()))+1;
}
```

Мои грубые замеры показали, что такой вариант работает в несколько раз быстрее, чем способ через длину строки:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    BigInteger integer = BigInteger.ONE;
    //увеличиваем значения на 11 (для чистоты эксперимента - чтобы log10 не был целым) каждые 1_000_000 итераций
    BigInteger multiplier = BigInteger.valueOf(11);
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<1_000_000; j++){
            logLength(integer);
        }
        integer = integer.multiply(multiplier);
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("log10: " + ((double)(end - start))/1000);
    integer = BigInteger.ONE;
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<1_000_000; j++){
            strLength(integer);
        }
        integer = integer.multiply(multiplier);
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("strlen: " + ((double)(end - start))/1000);
}

private static int strLength(BigInteger i){
    return i.toString(10).length();
}
```

Результаты:

```
log10: 0.387
strlen: 1.768
```

**PS**:
Спасибо @default locale за конструктивные комментарии насчет точности метода

Comment: [`BigInteger.doubleValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#doubleValue()) возвращает [бесконечность](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY) для значений превышающих [`Double.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE). Протестируйте на числе в 400 десятичных знаков, например.

Comment: вы правы, я добавлю это ограничение в ответ

Comment: Есть еще одна проблема. При преобразовании в `double` происходит потеря точности. Проверьте например на `999999999999999` (15 девяток)

Comment: верно, выходит, что метод в том виде, что я написал, успешно работает для неширокого диапазона чисел - от 1 до 99 999 999 999 999 (верхняя граница грубая, т.к. для большинства 15-значных тоже работает, но не всех)

Comment: Да, точности `double` хватает примерно на 15 разрядов. Для такого диапазона целесообразнее использовать `long` (18 разрядов). Как альтернативу можно написать свой логарифм для `BigInteger` через `bitLength`, но в этом случае также нужно будет строго оценить точность вычисления.

Answer (score -2):

```
while(n!=0) {
n=n/10;
i++
}
System.out.print(i);
```

в цикле делишь на 10 и увеличиваешь счётчик пока число не превратится в 0

Comment: BigInteger же, он не делится стандартным оператором

Comment: ну как варинат внести в строку и вывести длину строки, нет?

Comment: @etki правильно говорит, так нельзя делать с BigInteger, в этом и проблема!

Comment: @m1zl-s, можете написать кусочек кода со строкой?

Comment: Ну просто вместо запроса BigInteger запрашивайте строку и выводите ее длину